# Почему не работает Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

почему не работает jquery? такое впечатление, что я подключаю пустой файл, но он то не пустой.пути правильные, в чем может быть еще проблема? подключаю `<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>`

[image: фото ошибки]

Comment: Вам красным по белому написано, что по данному пути нет такого файла (404), это как бы намекает, что пути не правильные.

Comment: пути верные. сто раз было проверено уже, ладно, спасибо

Comment: Покажите url. Но я на 99% уверен, что вы путаете пути на файловой системе и url для браузера.

Answer (score 0):

1)Script теги советую ставить в самом низу body тега
2)Скрипты которые писали вы должны быть после главных скриптов то есть например идет jquery а потом ваш скрипт
3)попробуйте ставить этот тег в body

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```